# When is an ideal proper and a ring a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a nontrivial ring and $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Prove that $I$ is proper if and only if every element of $A$ is not a unit. From this statement (which must be proven), I must deduce that $A$ is a field if and only if it has exactly two ideals.

Comment: The first part is not correct.

Comment: Why? I need to prove that I is a proper ideal if and only if every element of the ring A is not a unit.

Comment: Repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3846219/29335 except with an additional request.

Comment: @CarmenMaría You should not post the same question twice in an hour. You should edit the first one.  Also, please take more time to [read the guidelines that were previously linked to you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for advice on question quality. You don't appear to be including enough context.